# Overwriting Key Value Pairs Versus Creating New One for Different Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, overwrite

My Goal:

```
{0: {'0':'0', '1':'1'), 1: {'0':'2', '1':'3'}, 2: {'0':'4','1':'0'}, 3:{'0':'1','1':'2'}, 4:{'0':'3' ,'1':'4' }}
```

What I am Getting:

```
{0: {'1': '1'}, 1: {'1': '3'}, 2: {'1': '0'}, 3: {'1': '2'}, 4: {'1': '4'}}
```

Therefore it is only storing the '1's part and overwriting the '0's part but I am unsure how to fix this issue because everything I seem to read says it should either update if it exists or create if it doesn't. 
Few Notes: state is 0 through 4, alphabet is ['0','1'] value is just a single char from a text file.

Here is my code:

```
for state in range(0, numStates):
    for letter in alphabet:
        value = DFAFileLines[state+3].split()[alphabet.index(letter)]
        print("State: " + str(state) + " Letter: " + letter +" Value: " + value)
        itemDict = dict()
        itemDict[letter] = value
        transitionTable[state] = itemDict
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and add enough code (and maybe data) so there is something executable the will reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up having to add default values into the dictionary when origianlly defining the dictionaries and it worked fine. (Note this was a previous version of the code I had tried not what I had at the time of posting) Here is the updated code:

```
transitionTable = dict(dict())
for state in range(0, numStates):
    transitionTable[state] = {k: 0 for k in alphabet}

for state in range(0, numStates):
    for letter in alphabet:
        value = DFAFileLines[state+3].split()[alphabet.index(letter)]
        stateDict = transitionTable[state]
        stateDict[letter] = value
```

The difference in what I originally had is

```
transitionTable[state] = {k for k in alphabet}
```

and now

```
transitionTable[state] = {k: 0 for k in alphabet}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the original code is that you are resetting `itemDict` each time through the inner loop and you should also assign `transitionTable` once per the outer for loop for the state key

```
for state in range(0, numStates):
        itemDict = dict()
        for letter in alphabet:
            value = DFAFileLines[state+3].split()[alphabet.index(letter)]
            print("State: " + str(state) + " Letter: " + letter +" Value: " + value)
            itemDict[letter] = value
        transitionTable[state] = itemDict
```